# JHipster React Front End (Gateway) Application Properties

Tags: reactjs, microservices, jhipster

I'm building a JHipster microservice application, consisting of Microservice, Registry and Gateway (React).
In the Microservice application I can use the application.yml / ApplicatioProperties.java to add properties (such as API keys) which may change between environments (Dev, Prod etc).

My question is, can I do the same thing on the React front-end? This is a Spring application so the same application.yml and ApplicationProperties.java are in place. Does anyone have a code example of surfacing custom properties to the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [AuthInfoResource](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/web/rest/AuthInfoResource.java.ejs) that takes properties and makes them available at an `/api/auth-info` endpoint. You could so something similar to expose configuration properties to your React app.

```
package <%= packageName %>.web.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Resource to return information about OIDC properties
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AuthInfoResource {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri:}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oidc.client-id:}")
    private String clientId;


    @GetMapping("/auth-info")
    public AuthInfoVM getAuthInfo() {
        return new AuthInfoVM(issuer, clientId);
    }

    class AuthInfoVM {
        private String issuer;
        private String clientId;

        AuthInfoVM(String issuer, String clientId) {
            this.issuer = issuer;
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        public String getIssuer() {
            return this.issuer;
        }

        public void setIssuer(String issuer) {
            this.issuer = issuer;
        }

        public String getClientId() {
            return clientId;
        }

        public void setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }
    }
}
```